# There is a jquery slider on my site. Adding other jquery slide disables the jquery slider

Tags: jquery

There is a jquery slider on my site. If I add any other jquery, like say I want a scroll to top functionality and i include it, scroll to top works but slider stops working. why is that so?

This is the site: www.placementor.blogspot.com. The code i use is:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    }); 

    $('.scrollup').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
        return false;
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.scrollup{
width:40px;
height:40px;
opacity:0.3;
position:fixed;
bottom:50px;
right:100px;
display:none;
text-indent:-9999px;
background: url('icon_top.png') no-repeat;
```

}

I have tried removing:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

thinking that it would be redundant as the slider might be using some plugin and is creating a conflict. But no it still doesn't work. Help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Issue #1 - You're using MooTools, so you'll need to use `.noConflict()` to avoid issues with the MooTools library and jQuery

```
/* As a new variable */
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

/* or, by using a closure */
(function($j){
    //your code
})(jQuery);
```

Issue #2 -- You're not actually including the jQuery file on your site. jQuery must be included before any scripts attempt to use the `jQuery namespace`.

Fix these problems and you'll be good.